# 8024402F windows updates error Windows 7 ?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

It started from Unable to resolve the DNS server address in several pages and then I found out that windows updates doesn't work. It gives me 8024402F problem, I tried this

1. Start → **Services.msc**
2. Stop the "**Background Intelligent Transfer**" and "**Windows
   Update**" services.
3. Start → Cmd ('as administrator')

   ```
   rd %systemroot%\softwaredistribution /s
   ```
4. Go back to services and start **Windows Update service**.
5. Try updates again.

It didn't work

I tried change date and time settings didn't work also

Any suggestion ?

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/1085847/8024402f-windows-updates-error-windows-7, for a pile of answers to this question

Answer (score 1):

Error `0x8024402F` means `WU_E_PT_ECP_SUCCEEDED_WITH_ERRORS`:

> // MessageId: WU_E_PT_ECP_SUCCEEDED_WITH_ERRORS 
>   // 
>   // MessageText: 
>   //
>   // External cab file processing completed with some errors. 
>   // #define **WU_E_PT_ECP_SUCCEEDED_WITH_ERRORS** _HRESULT_TYPEDEF_(**0x8024402F**L)

Stop the Windows Update service, delete the content of the folder `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download`. Also [exclude this folder from your Anti Virus suite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd939908%28WS.10%29.aspx#av).

Now try again to run Windows Update.